# Where to add this query/function? So, that it works all over the app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have Bottom Navigation Bar which have total 5 Navigations in it and in one of the Bottom Navigation(HOME NAV:- it is the first screen when user visits app) and in it there is further have TabBar which have 4 Tabs. In first TAB there are post by every other user and current user can like/dislike that post. And I have one functionality in it that if user see that post then it should not appear again. Now the problem I am facing is if user stays only on HOME NAVIGATION which comes on launch and see all the post and goes to some other TAB which are located in HOME NAVIGATION only then it works fine but if user switch to some other Bottom Navigation item then visit again in HOME NAV then all the post starts again which user has already seen. I have also added this FUNCTION getUserList to check which user has already seen but it on only works when user switches in between the TABS and not when user switch to some other Bottom Navigation item and visit again. Pls help me to put the function on a right place so that it should work all the time.

```
 Future getUserList() async {
    List checkedUser = [];
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
   
        .collection('/users/${currentUser.uid}/CheckedUser')
        .get()
        .then((data) {
      checkedUser.addAll(data.docs.map((f) => f.data().containsKey(['DislikedUser'])));
      checkedUser.addAll(data.docs.map((f) => f.data().containsKey(['LikedUser'])));
    }).then((_) {
      query().get().then((data) async {
        if (data.docs.length < 1) {
          print("no more data");
          return;
        }
        users.clear();
        userRemoved.clear();

      });
    });
  }
```

This is the Bottom TAB:-

```
 Widget findWidget(int index){
    if(index == 0)
      return Home();
    else if(index == 1)
      return UserProfile(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser, imageList: [], currentIndex: 0);
    else if(index == 2)
      return Notifications();
    else if(index == 3)
      return Chat();
    else
      return More();
  }
```

And this is TAB Bar which is inside Home Nav:-

```
 body: TabBarView(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: [
                     Center(child : SwipeScreen(currentUser, users, swipecount)),
                      Icon(Icons.movie),
                      Icon(Icons.games),
                      Icon(Icons.online_prediction)
                    ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not very sure if this is what you want, but still give it a try.

If you want your widget to continue from where you left and not re-render then you can do this with `KEY`.

Basically, you need to pass the same key every-time a class is rendered for flutter to know to not re-render it again in the future.

To do this accept a key in your `Home()` class

```
   class Home extends StatefulWidget
   {
     Key key;
     Home(key);
   }
```

And use it like this:

```
if(index == 0)
  return Home(Key('Home'));
```

And this should prevent flutter from re-rendering it again.

NOTE: There might be cases where you need the widget to re-render. In that case you will have to put some of your own logic.

Comment: Is it a Stateful or Stateless widget ?

Comment: Every screen is Stateful

Comment: Did you add your function in the init() function of your Home screen and try ??

Comment: yes I have. the function which calling them is in init only.

Comment: Ya, send me a link, lets hop on a call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233371/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-nitesh).